# convert NSData to UIImage in iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to convert nsdata into uiimage and display in imageview.

data is coming from database like this

```
NSData *imgdata = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(cmp_sqlstmt,1)
                                         length:sqlite3_column_bytes(cmp_sqlstmt,1)];
```

I tried this code

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imgdata];

//set image to imageview
[img setImage:image];
```

but image is not showing. How do I solve this?

Comment: What type of image are you trying to load ? and did you make sure the data is read properly ?

Comment: UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:sqlite3_column_blob(cmp_sqlstmt,1)];

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your `imgdata` is correct?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a code example for JPEG, you can set the compression from 0 to 1 in decimals:

```
UIImage *yourimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png];
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0);
```

Edit:

There you go

```
NSData *yourData = somedata
UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageWithData:yourData];
```

Comment: i want to convert nsdata in to uiimage.this is my code  NSData *imgdata = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(cmp_sqlstmt,1)
                                         length:sqlite3_column_bytes(cmp_sqlstmt,1)];. I want to convert this nsdata in to uiimage

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
UIImage *imageObj = yourImage

 NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageObj);


profileImage.image= [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

Comment: i want to convert nsdata in to uiimage